# Remove comma with regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to remove a comma that is located in a line of text.
I need to remove a comma after the 7th comma.

I can use this `^[^,\n]*((,[^,\n]*){14}$)` to locate the rows I want. So anything > 14 I need to remove the 7th comma.

1. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
2. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
3. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
4. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,8,,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
5. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

Comment: Why don't you just replace two commas `,,` with one?

Comment: In the actual data sometimes there is a space sometimes not space it various.

Comment: so if there is > 14 commas i need to remove the 7th comma

Comment: Ok i now get what you mean with "anything > 14". However the problem is still not quite clear to me. in line 4 you have `,,` twice. Should only the 7th comma be deleted?

Comment: yes the 7th comma needs to be deleted from example 2,3, and 4. Example 1 and 5 are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the first 6 comma's, and then use `\K` to clear the match buffer.

Then match the 7th comma to be matched and replaced with an empty string, and assert at least 7 more comma's to the right afterwards.

```
^[^,\n]*(?:,[^,\n]*){6}\K,(?=[^,\n]*(?:,[^,\n]*){7})
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^,\n]*(?:,[^,\n]*){6}` Match the first 6 comma's
- `\K,` Forget what is matched so far, and match the 7th comma
- `(?=[^,\,]*(?:,[^,\n]*){7})` positive lookahead, assert 7 more comma's to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0knTxw/1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove the 7th comma from lines containing 15 commas or more replace:

```
(?=(?:\w*,){15,})((?:,\w*){6}),
```

With

```
\1
```

Explanation:

- `(?=(?:\w*,){15,})` is a lookahead checking that the line contains 15 commas or more
- `((?:,\w*){6})` is the first and only group of our regular expression. It captures the first six commas and the following word
- `,` is the 7th comma you want to delete
- `\1` we replace the whole match with our captured group

Note: with this kind of expression you might delete the wrong comma in cases following this pattern:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,,11,12,13,14,15
```